# LibreOffice: How to change the style of the superscript text by default?

Tags: libreoffice, fonts

I have LibreOffice 5.3.3.2 on Ubuntu 16.04 (xubuntu).

Now the superscript is too small:

[image]

I can increase the font size for the superscript text (*Format → Character → Position*), but only for one character. I have two questions:

1. How can I change the style of all superscript text?
2. One more problem. If the superscript is too large, then the interval between the lines increases. So how to reduce this interval?

   [image]

Comment: Try to modify the default style (or whatever you are using): From `Format->Styles and Formatting` select `Default Style`and with right mouse `Modify` (context menu). Things you change here are defaults, e.g. `Position` or `Indents & Spacing`. Play with those values to meet your needs.

Comment: @ridgy, the default style changes the entire paragraph. I want to change the style of only one character.

Comment: While your question is on topic here, you'll likely receive better answers on https://ask.libreoffice.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you will have to create a new SuperScript Style, and apply it to all your superscript text, instead of just 'superscripting' it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or a toolbar icon.

You can do it by opening the Styles and Formatting sidebar (View -> Styles and Formatting (<kbd>F11</kbd>)), clicking Character Styles at the sidebar header, then selecting any superscript character in your text, then clicking the New Style from Selection dropdown at the sidebar header and choosing New Style. Give it a name. It will be a default superscript character style, which you can now modify. Right click on it in the sidebar and choose Modify to do it. When you are finished, you will have to manually select all the superscript characters you want to change and select your newly created style in the sidebar.

Yes, this is not a perfect way to do it, but

1. you will have to set your style parameters only once and then only apply it;
2. you can easily change the style of all your superscript characters later at once.

This is the best way I can think of, until we find a better way!)